# Não estou conseguindo me conectar com o postgreSQL no php

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de Login em PHP usando o PostgreSQL porém, não consigo fazer minha aplicação se conectar com o Banco de Dados. segue o código:

```
 <?php
     $connect = pg_connect("dbname=testebd"); //Banco de dados previamente criado
     if (!$connect)
     {
        echo "Conexão não realizada";
     } else 
     {
        echo "Conexão bem sucedida";
     }
?>
```

Quando executo minha aplicação, absolutamente nada acontece. A pagina fica totalmente em branco. Não consigo nem mesmo imprimir o conteudo da variavel:

```
$connect = pg_connect("dbname=testebd");
echo "$connect";
```

Alguem sabe me dizero porque a conexão não está sendo realizada?. Obs: Uso o servidor Apache em um Ubuntu e consigo utilizar normalmente o postegreSQl pelo bash.

Comment: ative as mensagens de erro do php

Comment: Página em branco e erro 500, querem dizer erro de programação. Habilite a exibição dos erros, adicionando essas duas linhas no começo do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Agora o erro que está aparecendo quando eu faco           if(!($conexao= pg_connect ("host=localhost dbname=iluminecar port=5432 user=sullyvan password="))) 
  {
      print "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados.";
  } else {
      pg_close ($conexao);
      print "Conexão OK!"; 
  }                                                                                                                   é Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 24

Comment: Consegui resolver, instalei o php5-pgsql e setei display_errors = on

Comment: pg_connect foi depreciado.
Está no manual do PHP, ou seja, só nas versões antigas que funciona. https://www.php.net/pg_connect

Comment: Olá Frederico. Apenas para informar e evitar mal-entendidos `depreciado` não é a tradução de `deprecated`, é a tradução de `depreciated`, são palavras distintas. A tradução aproximada correta de `deprecated`  pode ser `obsoleto`, `desaprovado`, `censurado`. No caso de uso aqui o melhor com certeza é `obsoleto`. Resumindo `depreciado` e `depreciated` nada tem haver com "obsoleto". Segundo ponto, em nenhum lugar da documentação está afirmando que pg_connect esta obsoleto. Não use o campo o *Sua resposta* para comentários, recomendo que faça o [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º Ative as mensagens de erro do seu PHP:

Abra este arquivo com seu editor preferido: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Procure esta linha:

```
display_errors = Off
```

e troque por esta:

```
display_errors = On
```

Após isso, reinicie o apache (no terminal):

```
service apache2 restart
```

Com base nisso, pegue a mensagem de erro e coloque aqui.

Mas, para adiantar, segue um exemplo de conexão com o postgres:

```
<?php
if(!@($conexao=pg_connect ("host=HOST dbname=BANCO port=5432 user=LOGIN password=SENHA"))) {
   print "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados.";
} else {
   pg_close ($conexao);
   print "Conexão OK!"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vai conectar dessa forma, é necessário informar o dsn completo, com host, usuário e senha além do banco de dados.

```
$connect = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=teste user=usario password=senha");
```

Answer (score 0):

A Versão do PHP 7.1 está instável e cheia de bugs (mais de 30 páginas de erro no site php). Um destes erros é que o PHP não consegue enxergar os módulos necessários para executar os comando pg_connect ou o PDO do pgsql.  E não se trata de simples configuração do arquivo php.ini, mas de um erro interno.  Para conectar com o postgresql é necessário voltar à versão 5.x.