# Conexão php a banco de dados PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Problema ao realizar conexão com banco de dados PostgreSQL utilizando PHP. 
Quando executo a função `pg_conect()`, ocorre o seguinte erro

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

já adicionei o caminho da dll do postgreSQL para o httpd

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/libpq.dll"
```

e também ativei as extensões do php, no php.ini removendo o `;` extension=php_pgsql.dll

Sempre que executo o código para verificar se a extensão está ativa ele me retona erro

```
echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'Ok':'Erro';
```

Atualmente utilizo o wampserv com apache2.4.9 e php5.5.12. Como posso resolver esse erro? é possivel resolver a alterando a versão, já que fazendo essas alterações não consigo?
Como consigo fazer com que o php tenha acesso ao pgsql? já que minha aplicação não é capaz de encontrá-la ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Não estou conseguindo me conectar com o postgreSQL no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100445/n%c3%a3o-estou-conseguindo-me-conectar-com-o-postgresql-no-php)

Comment: Olá, a pergunta de certa forma é semelhante mas a resposta desse link não é capaz de resolver meu erro, vou editar a pergunta para ficar mais clara

Answer (score -1):

O problema consistia na versão referente ao wamp e suas ferramentas, desinstalei a versão que estava usando 2.* e instalei a versão mais atual. realizei os procedimento novamente de habilitar o pgsql, removendo o ; do php.ini, e agora ele conseguiu encontrar a extensão e se conectar ao PostgreSQL