# Erro conexão do PostgreSQL com o CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, postgresql

Erro conexão do PostgreSQL com o CodeIgniter:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230497/5878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que ativar a dll do postgres no arquivo php.ini do xampp, descomente essa linha retirando o `;`, senão nenhum comando vai funcionar.

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: Obrigadaa!!!!!!

Comment: Me positive aí por favor, já respondi outra pergunta sua novamente. Se não souber como fazer, faça o **tour** do site, é rapido e fácil também. Só entre nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour .Até mais.

Comment: Lembrando que a instalação do _PHP_ deve ter essa biblioteca instalada, senão o erro vai ser outro. Ou seja, não adianta descomentar a linha se vc ainda não instalou a biblioteca no local correto no servidor.