# Erro Undefined property: Produtos::$db no Codegniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou seguindo o tutorial de um video para criar um crud no Codegnaiter, estou usando o banco PostgreSQL e o Xampp

MODEL:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Produtos_model extends CI_Model {

    //Lista todos os produtos da tabela produtos    
    public function getProdutos() {
        $query = $this->db->get("produtos");
        return $query->result();
    }

    //Adiciona um novo produtos na tabela produtos
    public function addProduto($dados = NULL) {
        if ($dados != NULL):
            $this->db->insert('produtos', $dados);
            endif;
        }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Produtos extends CI_Controller {

    //Página de listar produtos
    public function index() {
        //Carrega o Model Produto
        $this->load->model('produtos_model', 'produtos');
        //Criamos um Array dados para armazenas os produtos
        //Executamos a função no produtos_model getProdutos
        $data['produtos'] = $this->produtos->getProdutos();
        //Carregamos a view listarprodutos e passamos como parametro a array produtos que guarda todos os produtos da db produtos
        $this->load->view('listarprodutos', $data);
    }

    //Página de adicionar produto
    public function add() {
        //Carrega o Model Produtos              
        $this->load->model('produtos_model', 'produtos');
        //Carrega a View
        $this->load->view('addprodutos');
    }

    //Função salvar no DB
    public function salvar() {
        //Verifica se foi passado o campo nome vazio.
        if ($this->input->post('nome') == NULL) {
            echo 'O compo nome do produto é obrigatório.';
            echo '<a href="/produtos/add" title="voltar">Voltar</a>';
        } else {
            //Carrega o Model Produtos              
            $this->load->model('produtos_model', 'produtos');
            //Pega dados do post e guarda na array $dados
            $dados['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');
            $dados['preco'] = $this->input->post('preco');
            $dados['ativo'] = $this->input->post('ativo');

            //Executa a função do produtos_model adicionar
            $this->produtos->addProduto($dados);
            //Fazemos um redicionamento para a página       
            redirect("/");                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me aponte a linha que dá o erro nesses códigos! eu to achando que é na hora de renomear o model!

Comment: Linha 8 que está dando erro do model  public function getProdutos() {

Comment: Biblioteca de conexão PHP com _PostgreSQL_ + biblioteca de conexão com banco do _CodeIgniter_. Se as duas não estiverem carregadas e funcionando os sintomas são esses aí.

Comment: Essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235917/erro-conex%c3%a3o-do-postgresql-com-o-codeigniter) não é sua? Se vc resolveu o problema descrito lá, não devia estar tendo o problema descrito aqui...

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando consultar o banco, sem ter carregado a biblioteca de conexão.

Se for conectar apenas na hora, escreve isso no seu model:

```
$this->load->database(); //fará a conexão do banco padrão ou
$this->load->database('outra_conexao'); //faz a conexão de outro banco
```

Se seu site utiliza banco na maioria das páginas eu recomendo, você ir na suas pasta `config`, no arquivo `autoload.php` e editar essa linha:

```
$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Ainda melhor, recomendo dar um autoload na `session` também, ficando assim:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');
```

Aproveitando se você é iniciante em codeigniter, neste mesmo arquivo, edite a linha dos **helpers**, deixando assim:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html');
```

Outra configuração que você se esqueceu pelo visto, também na pasta `config` tem o arquivo `database.php`:

```
//pedaço que interessa...
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost', //servidor
    'username' => 'root', //usuario
    'password' => 'sua senha', //senha
    'database' => 'seu banco', //banco
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre', //aqui é o tipo de conexão usada
//resto do codigo não mexe
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco o database  no autoload da esse erro: Message: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Comment: tudo que tento criar no codegnaiter está dando esse erro, sou iniciante não sei como funciona ainda, estou apenas seguindo os tutoriais

Comment: Testa ai essa configuração no `autoload.php` que vai dar certo, ai me pontua aqui novamente, obrigado.

Comment: Eu testei, ainda não deu certo :(

Comment: E o seu arquivo `database.php` também no mesmo diretório, você configurou? Vou atualizar minha resposta, confere aí.

Comment: Sim, também ja configurei o database.php

Answer (score 1):

Atualiza sua pergunta com o código do seu `autoload.php` e `database.php` também, mas erro de **properties**, costuma ser configuração errada geralmente no **php.ini**. Você pode tentar utilizar conexao **PDO** em vez da tradicional descomentando essa linha `;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` e alterando seu **database.php** essas duas linhas para:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:host=seu_servidor;dbname=seubanco';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //set driver here
```

As demais linhas permanecem iguais.

Ah... apesar de ser bem improvável, não custa eu perguntar, você já reiniciou seu servidor desde a primeira alteração no `php.ini` né? Se não, não vai dar certo mesmo.